# Dubai immigration problem

Tags: customs-and-immigration, dubai

My brother has a bank debit problem in Dubai and he came back India 2010 his name is Vinod Sharma s/o. Ravinder Sharma. i hope his name is in Uae airport immigration.if I go Dubai? my name is Ragav Sharma S/o. Ravinder Sharma. Is there any problem for me because my brother's surname and my surnames are the same? im planing to go dubai first time.

Comment: This is quite hard to understand what your problem is.  Are you saying he owes money? Have you had a look at our [help] on how to ask a question here?

Comment: I think he is asking if he will get in trouble when he travels to Dubai, because his brother, who has the same surname, is in trouble for owning banks some money.

Comment: You will not get into trouble; because I am willing to bet you are not the only person that has the same surname as your brother. Debts of your brother are not obligatory to you. If your brother is trying to flee though, or you are trying to help him flee - then you will both be in serious trouble.